# Drop all objects on schema in Oracle

Tags: oracle

I'm trying to build a script to delete all objects on a database, so with the following select, build a procedure to execute that will leave the database completely clean (without having permissions to drop the database and creating it again). First remove all sequences, indexes, etc, and then the tables.

```
select 'drop '||object_type||' '|| object_name || ';' from user_objects where object_type in ('VIEW','PACKAGE','SEQUENCE', 'PROCEDURE', 'FUNCTION', 'INDEX')
```

With that in mind I thought something like this could work:

```
BEGIN

    FOR i IN (select 'drop '||object_type||' '|| object_name || ';' from user_objects where object_type in ('VIEW','PACKAGE','SEQUENCE', 'PROCEDURE', 'FUNCTION', 'INDEX'))
    LOOP
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE i;
    END LOOP;

END;
/
```

But I get:

> Error report - ORA-06550: line 5, column 27: PLS-00382: expression is
>   of wrong type ORA-06550: line 5, column 9: PL/SQL: Statement ignored
>   06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
>   *Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
>   *Action:

Any idea how to perform this?

Comment: Why not simply `DROP USER ... CASCADE;`

Comment: Why do you like to drop first the indexes and then the tables? All indexes of a table will be dropped also if you drop the table. What about Materialized views?

Comment: `DROP` and `CREATE` user is of course elegant, but requires extra privileges.

Comment: Just skip the `';'`

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit user has no privileges to do a drop user (can't drop itself either). You mean skipping the ';' in the select statement?

Comment: Yes, the string for `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` must not terminate with semicolon.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`execute immediate` needs a string (or varchar2) argument. You are giving it a cursor row. Give your selected value an alias and use that as the argument, and don't include the semicolon in the statement, like this:

```
begin
  for i in (select 'drop ' || object_type || ' ' || object_name as stmt
              from user_objects
             where object_type in ('VIEW', 'PACKAGE', 'SEQUENCE', 'PROCEDURE', 'FUNCTION', 'INDEX')) loop
    execute immediate i.stmt;
  end loop;
end;
/
```

Comment: +1 for your help. This will throw the error when the object type is not available. Kindly make sure you are passing only required object types like TABLE, SEQUENCE, etc. When you are dropping the table, it also drops the related indexes. So no need to explicitly mention INDEX unless you have few indexes which are not associated with tables.

Comment: Got error as `ORA-02449: unique/primary keys in table referenced by foreign keys`

Comment: @Bishan The statement for dropping tables can be modified to: `DROP TABLE <table_name> CASCADE CONSTRAINTS`. The CASCADE CONSTRAINTS option will also drop any foreign key constraints referencing the table being dropped, thus avoiding that error.

Comment: @GriffeyDog Yeah, achieved with `CASCADE CONSTRAINTS`. Thanks for the update.

Answer (score 2):

For testing purposes, I use Scott's schema. Once it gets too polluted, I'm dropping everything but Scott's default tables. This is my script; see if it helps in your case.

Note that you'll have to run it several times as it doesn't take care about foreign key constraints which won't let you drop master tables while their details exist, but that doesn't bother me much.

```
declare
  l_str varchar2(200);
begin
  for cur_r in (select object_name, object_type From user_objects 
                where object_name not in ('EMP', 'DEPT', 'BONUS', 'SALGRADE')
               )
  loop
    begin
      l_str := 'drop ' || cur_r.object_type || ' '|| cur_r.object_name;
      dbms_output.put_Line(l_str);
      execute immediate l_str;
    exception
      when others then null;
    end;
  end loop;
end;
/
```

Comment: Actual question was "drop all objects" what IMHO should include Queues, etc. So that is still not finally answered. My guess is that Oracle RDBMS would need to properly support this like some other DBs. As it does not, there is no fully working solution available and you have to drop and recreate the user. If you do not have according permission it ends up with lots of manual fiddling :(

Comment: Certainly, @Jörg. I don't know anyone who actually drops all objects from a schema that is being used for production purposes. *Maybe* for educational purposes (i.e. *every new student gets its own clean schema*), but I'd rather drop the old user and **import** a new, clean one. Code I posted is OK for my Scott user which is being used to answer questions I find on various Oracle forums/sites. I'm too lazy to drop/import so I run that code and I'm satisfied with what it does.

Comment: IMHO nobody does this in production, but in test-environments close to dev this is quite normal with liquibase or flyway. BTW: An alternative workaround for Oracle is to create the SQL idempotent as kind of "CREATE IF NOT EXISTS" (pseudo syntax, use web-search to find real SQL for actual cases).